# sharing source file between two projects in one solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linker

I know how to do it in C++ with `#include`, but I actually can't understand how make it with c# `usings`

So. I have project that work with some data files. I have my own "Serializer" class for it. And I also want make simple console tool to work with those data files. This tool depends on "Serializer" too. Both projects in one solution.

I try "Add existed item" but it only makes a copy.

Actually i didn't want made separate projects. But it looks one project == one entry point.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to *share source* (as title asks) or just refer to the other assembly (as answers suggest)? Please clarify your question so answers can be properly voted on.

Comment: I need use class in this file. Thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to add an item, you want to add a project reference.

To do this, right click on "References", then "Add Reference".

[image]

Choose the project you want to add a reference to:

[image]

Then include the using statement:

[image]

In your case, you would want

```
using hello.Helpers;
```

Comment: Looks logical, but didn't work. `using hello;` work nice (root namespace). `using hello.Helpers;` don't see `Serializer`

Comment: do you see `Serializer` when you just add `using hello;`?

Comment: Hmm. I can write directly in code `hello.Algo.<Some class in Algo>` to see this class (`using hello;` only). But I cant make it with Helpers folder. All other class/namespaces is Ok.

Comment: @StepanLoginov Is your serializer class made public? Can you share the signature of your serializer class. The line of code where Serializer class is declared. Make sure Serializer class is declared as `public`

Comment: Yeap public is missed. public + rebuild solution is an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a file/class placed in one project from other project you can add its namespace in your calling project, if that's what you are asking.

For instance, If your Serializer class is placed in projectA, in order to use it you might be creating an object of it or may be you have static methods in that class, whatever the case may be, you can add the reference of projectA in projectB. You can do that by right clicking on `References` of projectB and clicking `Add reference` and add projectA's reference in projectB. This way you can create objects of Serializer or call its static methods from within projectB without making its copy.